# POST variables appear in PHP symbol table

Tags: php

I discovered that my POST variables are being assigned as variables within my script.

This behavior doesn't seem right to me.  The elements of $_POST and $_GET are appearing in the symbol table as extracted variables without me explicitly doing setting them..

The following example shows what I mean.  The script is called with

> http://localhost/test_script.php?select=1

and the variable $select is already set and in the symbol table when the script executes.  Is there an explanation for this?  I thought I had to extract($_POST) or set the variable explicitly, e.g. $select = $_POST['select'];

Here is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>                     
<?php 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars())); 
echo "</pre>"; 
echo "\$select = $select";  
die; ?>
```

Here is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => GLOBALS
    [1] => _ENV
...
    [31] => select
...
    [59] => argv
    [60] => argc
    [61] => _POST
    [62] => _GET
    [63] => _COOKIE
    [64] => _SERVER
    [65] => _FILES
    [66] => _REQUEST
)
$select = 1
```

PHP Version is 5.2.9-1

**ARGHH!  Just solved my own problem.**  The register_globals directive was set "On" in php.ini.  I have disabled it, as it is supposed to be.  I'll just leave this here in case somebody else notices the same issue.

Cheers
Jeff

Comment: [Register Globals](http://php.net/security.globals) is exactly what I was about to ask for.

Comment: This might seen odd, but you should answer the question yourself and accept it for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Is Register_globals enabled?  If it is then you really should consider turning it off because of both the confusion it can cause, but more importantly it's a terrible security risk.

Comment: As I said, I disabled it immediately.  It was, however, only on my local server, not on the remote server.